# How can I select elements from a pulldown list

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Ok, that sounds too generic.  I have been able to do this in other areas and I am not sure what is different here.

I have this little snippet of html in the page of my system under test:

```
<select id="TransferUnit" name="TransferUnit">
<option value="GB" selected="selected">GB</option>
<option value="TB">TB</option>
</select>
```

Pretty simple, right. From selenium, I can open the pulldown by issuing a .click() on the select element.  I can check that the two options are visible with .is_displayed().  I can check if it is selected with .is_selected().  But I can't get .click() to change which element in the list is selected.

Of course this works when I try it manually.  But I am having a lot of trouble automating it.

Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: Are you using the IDE or are you doing this programatically using WebDriver or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IDE, perform a click on an element with a locator like this:

```
xpath="//option[@value='TB']"
```

Comment: Ok, that got me on the right path. but I still had to do something very ugly.

element.click
{time.sleep(.1)
element.click
time.sleep(.2)}

I feel very dirty about that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this doc](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#user-input-filling-in-forms), you can do one of the following:

Either

```
// even when the drop down is not expanded
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='TB']").click();
```

or

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select"))
select.deselect_all()
select.select_by_visible_text("TB")
```

[The Python doc for `Select`.](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html)

If neither works, then update your Selenium version (the current one is 2.22.0) and your browser, if possible - for example the fully supported Firefoxes are 3.6.*, 10, 11, 12.

If still nothing works, look for nasty Javascripts blowing up our efforts.

Comment: While I am selected a different answer, I do need to spend some time looking into that python doc for Select.  I truly appreciate you sharing it.  It should improve my work in the future.